# Sys.Date() showing the wrong date

Tags: r, macos, date

I do not know what happened but am getting irritated with this. I am currently in the GMT-8 Time Zone. When I type `Sys.Date()` it returns the tomorrow's date.

As of now the current date & time is 12/7/17 10:41 PM: 
I type `Sys.time()` and this is what i get:

```
Sys.time()
[1] "2017-12-08 14:37:22 GMT"
```

I then try to setup my time zone: `Sys.setenv(TZ=Sys.timezone())`

It clears without errors... and then I type `Sys.Date()` again and get

```
Sys.Date()
[1] "2017-12-08"
```

It should be 12/7/17 !!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `Sys.timezone()` on your system (after restarting R)? From its documentation: "If TZ is set but empty or invalid, most platforms default to UTC, the time zone colloquially known as GMT". `Sys.setenv(TZ=Sys.timezone())` would then set TZ to this.

Comment: When I type: `Sys.timezone()`i get `"GMT-8"`

Comment: Make a note time returned on your system is in `GMT`. `2017-12-08 14:37:22 GMT`. Hence you need to convert it to your local time to check validity.

Comment: What is your OS? On my Windows setup I get, e.g., `"Europe/Berlin"`.

Comment: @MKR but with a correct setup it shouldn't be in "GMT". It certainly isn't on my system.

Comment: Im using RStudio on Mac OS, I get the correct timezone on Windows. Im US/Los Angeles

Comment: If nobody else solves it I might try to look into this with my mac at home over the weekend. Do you use High Sierra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my mac system, I saw this with R 3.4.1 after updating to Mac OS 10.13.2:

```
Sys.time()
[1] "2017-12-08 20:52:01 GMT"
Warning:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin'
```

I could fix that by setting `Sys.setenv(TZ = "Europe/Berlin")`. Valid timezone names for the US can be found using `grep('^US/', OlsonNames(), value = TRUE)`.

After upgrading to R 3.4.3 I see this:

```
Sys.time()
[1] "2017-12-08 21:57:15 CET"

Sys.timezone()
#[1] "Europe/Berlin"
```

So this looks like an issue due to an OS update. In fact, the release notes for R 3.4.3 say this:

> A workaround has been added for the changes in location of time-zone
>   files in macOS 10.13 ‘High Sierra’ and again in 10.13.1, so the
>   default time zone is deduced correctly from the system setting when R
>   is configured with --with-internal-tzcode (the default on macOS).